# Creating two overlapped win32 windows simulatenously c++

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I tried to create two overlapped windows but only one popped up. I plan to use 1 window to handle the buttons and another separate window(not child) to show images that changes every 1 second. Is it possible? I tried to use 1 window to handle both but the buttons went missing and are unable to click because the program is busy running the display. And what parameter to set for the HINSTANCE for the second window?

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
  HWND hWnd;
 HWND hWnd2;
 hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
  100, 0,1000, 700, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

hWnd2= CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
  100, 0,1000, 700, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

         CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("\t Start Scanning\n"),
       WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            810, 320, 150, 150,
             hWnd, (HMENU) IDM_BEGIN, NULL, NULL);

         CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("\t STOP \n"),
       WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            810, 480, 150, 150,
             hWnd, (HMENU) IDM_PERMASTOP, NULL, NULL);




if (!hWnd)
  {
    return FALSE;
  }

  ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
  UpdateWindow(hWnd);

  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Use only one window. Use WM_TIMER to change image. Draw image in WM_PAINT. Add WS_CLIPCHILDREN to the Parent styles.

Comment: @manuell, absolutely brilliant answer. thank you very much for giving me the fix. Solved everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating two overlapped windows, but you are calling `ShowWindow()` on only the first time.  Simply call `ShowWindow()` on the other one as well.